# Write column based on DataFrame join

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Let's say I have two DataFrames -- `df1` and `df2` -- both with the columns `foo` and `bar`.  The column `foo` is a CRC32 hash value like `123456`, the column `bar` is a boolean field that defaults to `False`.

In pyspark, what is an efficient way to compare the values of `foo` across the two DataFrames, writing the column `bar` to `True` in the event they do **not** match.

e.g., given the following two DataFrames:

```
# df1
foo    | bar
-------|------
123456 | False
444555 | False
666777 | False
888999 | False

# df2
foo    | bar
-------|------
938894 | False
129803 | False
666777 | False
888999 | False
```

I woud like a new DataFrame that looks like the following, with two `True` columns where they hashes have changed:

```
# df3
foo    | bar
-------|------
938894 | True <---
129803 | True <---
666777 | False
888999 | False
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

### UPDATE 7/1/2018

After successful use of the accepted answer for quite some time, encountered a situation makes the solution not a great fit.  If multiple rows from one of the joined DataFrames have the same value for `foo` as a row from the other DataFrame in the join, it results in a cartesian product growth of rows on that shared value.

In my case, I had I had CRC32 hash values based on an empty string, which results in `0` for the hash.  I also should have added, that I do have a unique string to match the rows on, under `id` here (may have oversimplified situation), and perhaps **this is the thing to join on**:

It would create situations like this:

```
# df1
id   |foo    | bar
-----|-------|------
abc  |123456 | False
def  |444555 | False
ghi  |0      | False
jkl  |0      | False

# df2
id   |foo    | bar
-----|-------|------
abc  |123456 | False
def  |999999 | False
ghi  |666777 | False
jkl  |0      | False
```

And with the selected answer, would get a DataFrame with *more* rows than desired:

```
# df3
id   |foo    | bar
-----|-------|------
abc  |123456 | False
def  |999999 | True <---
ghi  |0      | False
jkl  |0      | False
jkl  |0      | False # extra row add through join
```

I'm going to keep the answer as selected, because it's a great answer to the question as originally posed.  But, any suggestions for how to handle DataFrames where the column `foo` may match, would be appreciated.

### ANOTHER UPDATE 7/1/2018, ALTERNATE ANSWER

I was over complicating the issue without the `id` column to join on.  When using that, it's relatively straightforward to join and write `transformed` column based on direct comparison of `fingerprint` column:

```
df2.alias("df2").join(df1.alias("df1"), df1.id == df2.id, 'left')\
    .select(f.col('df2.foo'), f.when(df1.fingerprint != df2.fingerprint, f.lit(True)).otherwise(f.col('df2.bar')).alias('bar'))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *aliased left join* of `df2` with `df1` and use of `when` function to check for the **not matched logic** should give you your desired output

```
df2.alias("df2").join(df1.alias("df1"), df1.foo == df2.foo, 'left')\
    .select(f.col('df2.foo'), f.when(f.isnull(f.col('df1.foo')), f.lit(True)).otherwise(f.col('df2.bar')).alias('bar'))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+------+-----+
|foo   |bar  |
+------+-----+
|129803|true |
|938894|true |
|888999|false|
|666777|false|
+------+-----+
```

Comment: That's the business!  Works great, thanks so much.  Selecting the column with a `when`/`otherwise` statement, and then `aliasing` as `bar`, that was the key to understanding how I could use that in other contexts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a left join and write the code such that when the data is null then you output false and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, I had figured the same, but having trouble envisioning the syntax.